# Вывод списка городов и выбор нужного

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно вывести выпадающий список с городами России и др. стран (не обязательно).

Я не знаю, где взять этот список и как его правильно вывести. Может, есть подобные библиотеки или статьи с описанием.

Answer (score 2):

Список городов ищем в [интернете](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8+json&safe=off).  
Выводим список городов через [Spinner](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/115-urok-56-spinner-vypadajuschij-spisok).

Answer (score 2):

Есть универсальный, стандартизированный список адресов [КЛАДР](http://gnivc.ru/inf_provision/classifiers_reference/kladr/), берите оттуда, ну а остальное дело техники.